# Is there any class similar to ProvidersHelper but not for web?

Tags: oracle10g, codesmith, .nettiers

Is there any class similar to ProvidersHelper but not for web?
I want to instantiate a collection of providers. Actually I'm using CodeSmith & Nettiers, and the db provider is Oracle. It generated a provider section to be added at app.config, and i dont know why it uses System.Web.Configuration classes or why at this section it says SQLClient instead of OracleClient.

The error that I'm getting is:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Web.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'LLPA.Data.OracleClient' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Any idea or solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bug if it refers to SQL Server and you are using Oracle. I'd recommend logging a bug on the [.netTiers issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/nettiers/). I'd recommend taking a look at all of the LLPA.Data.OracleClient project references are being built and ensure that they are in your bin directory of your compiled application.

Answer (score 0):

Check the DLL LLPA.Data.OracleClient is in the bin folder or the GAC. If that doesn't work look into using [Fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't had added the reference of `LLPA.Data.OracleClient` to my application, that's why it couldn't find it.

Comment: Haven't you forgotten to do something?